# Having a problem in building an existing java project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am importing an existing project in my eclipse. And I am getting this error, don't know how to fix it. I am searching for advice if any...

The below is the error shown:

> **Java Build Path Problem**
>
> *Archive for required library: '.project' in project 'C***ch2' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file*
>   [screenshot of errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYPLw.png)

**.classpath**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.server.core.container/org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.runtimeTarget/Apache Tomcat v7.0">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="owner.project.facets" value="jst.web"/>
    </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.web.container"/>
   <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path=".project"/>
   <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.module.container"/>
   <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.launching.macosx.MacOSXType/Java SE 11.0.1 [11.0.1]">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="owner.project.facets" value="java"/>
    </attributes>
   </classpathentry>
 <classpathentry kind="output" path="build/classes"/>
```

**.project**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
<name>C***ch2</name>
<comment></comment>
<projects>
</projects>
<buildSpec>
    <buildCommand>
        <name>org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.javascriptValidator</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
    <buildCommand>
        <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
    <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.builder</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
    <buildCommand>
        <name>org.eclipse.wst.validation.validationbuilder</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
</buildSpec>
<natures>
    <nature>org.eclipse.jem.workbench.JavaEMFNature</nature>
    <nature>org.eclipse.wst.common.modulecore.ModuleCoreNature</nature>
    <nature>org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.nature</nature>
    <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
    <nature>org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.jsNature</nature>
</natures>
```

Comment: Show us the contents of the `.classpath` and `.project` files - it looks like there is something substantially wrong in them.

Comment: @greg-449 i have added the .project and .classpath, is there any hint as to why the error is shown?

Comment: The line `<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path=".project"/>` in the classpath is wrong.

Comment: can you please show the correct way to be done

Answer (score 0):

The message is saying that the .project file isn't a valid library. It's not a jar file or a directory containing a folder structure of class files. Remove that entry from your project's Java Build Path.