# Having a problem in building an existing dynamic web project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, web, web-deployment-project

I am importing an existing project in my eclipse. And I am getting this error, don't know how to fix it. Could it be because of JRE or JDK version. I am kinda new to this so I am very lost. I am searching for advice if any...

The below is the error shown:

```
Java Build Path Problem

*Archive for required library: '.project' in project 'C***ch2' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file* screenshot of errors
```

This is the classpath

.classpath

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.server.core.container/org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.runtimeTarget/Apache Tomcat v7.0">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="owner.project.facets" value="jst.web"/>
    </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.web.container"/>
   <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path=".project"/>
   <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.module.container"/>
   <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.launching.macosx.MacOSXType/Java SE 11.0.1 [11.0.1]">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="owner.project.facets" value="java"/>
    </attributes>
   </classpathentry>
 <classpathentry kind="output" path="build/classes"/>
```

.project

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <projectDescription>
    <name>C***ch2</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
    <buildCommand>
        <name>org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.javascriptValidator</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
    <buildCommand>
        <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
    <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.builder</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
    <buildCommand>
        <name>org.eclipse.wst.validation.validationbuilder</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
</buildSpec>
<natures>
    <nature>org.eclipse.jem.workbench.JavaEMFNature</nature>
    <nature>org.eclipse.wst.common.modulecore.ModuleCoreNature</nature>
    <nature>org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.nature</nature>
    <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
    <nature>org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.jsNature</nature>
</natures>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Don't make a second question identical to your first one. [Having a problem in building an existing java project in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58929239/having-a-problem-in-building-an-existing-java-project-in-eclipse)

The message is saying that the .project file isn't a valid library. It's not a jar file or a directory containing a folder structure of class files. Remove that entry from your project's Java Build Path.

Comment: I delete the .classpath and .project file and rebuild and it works